# React Native Flatlist - using Redux for data prop......does not re-render when Redux state changes

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-flatlist

I pass Redux state into component as per below

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  rdx_userGPlaces: state.rdx_userGPlaces,
});
```

..then I pass redux state into FlatList component as follows:

```
return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={this.props.rdx_userGPlaces}
          ......etc
```

Redux state being passed in, is an array of "place" objects.....when the child object of one of these place objects changes.....FlatList does not re-render

Below is the action creator to update redux state

```
export const _actRefreshGPArray = gpArray => {
  return {
    type: REFRESH_GOOGLE_PLACES,
    payload: gpArray,
  };
};
```

...and the reducer

```
const userGPlacesReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REFRESH_GOOGLE_PLACES:
      return {...state, userGPlacesFiltered: action.payload};

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not mutating the `rdx_userGPlaces` array within state, instead of creating a new array when its value is updating?

Comment: Ive added the reducer to the original post

Comment: @jamesmurphy You maybe mutate it in the thunk? Code posted so far looks fine but I don't know why you use `rdx_userGPlaces` in component but `userGPlacesFiltered` in reducer.